# Generics for tuples

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to define generic variable as a Tuple?

The example:
lets use timer api and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

the first overload looks like:

```
var timeoutID = scope.setTimeout(function[, delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

the function is called with the param1, param2,... after certain period of the time.

How can be expressed that function accepts arguments of the same type as param1, param2, ...?

I tried:

```
public setTimeout<T>( 
callback:(...args: T) => void) | string, 
delay, ...args: T) {}
```

But it doesn't work as T can't hold tuples like [string, int].

Is there a way how to express this in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way I see of doing this is to declare several overloads of the function with  increasing number of parameters, with a fallback to `any[]` if the number of parameters is larger than a defined maximum. For most practical situations this should give the caller a good typed experience (in that parameters to the callback will have their parameter types inferred), even if the definition will be a lot more work to write. For setTimeout, 3 should be a sufficient number of parameters, but you could add more if necessary:

```
export declare function setTimeout<T1>( callback:(args1: T1) => void | string, args: T1);
export declare function setTimeout<T1, T2>( callback:(arg1: T1, arg2: T2) => void | string, arg1: T1, arg2: T2);
export declare function setTimeout<T1, T2, T3>( callback:(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3) => void | string, arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3);
export declare function setTimeout(callback:(...args: any[]) => void | string, ...args: any[]);


setTimeout((s,d)=> { 
    console.log(s);  // s is string
    d= d+1; // d is a number
}, "", 3);
```

The overload with `any[]` should be the last one in the list.

Note: If there is a mismatch between callback arguments and function arguments, the code will still compile as it falls back to the `any[]` version:

```
// Still compiles
setTimeout((s : string, d: string)=> { 
    // Code
}, "", 3);
```

Comment: That won't provide any type safety - if you call it with the wrong arguments, it will fallback to the "any" overload, instead of compile error.

Comment: You are right, it will only provide type inference for parameters to the callback based on parameters passed to the function ..

Comment: Edited the original answer to reflect feedback from @TomasNikodym